# Can we have readonly Field in Grid with cell Editor

Tags: extjs4.1

I am using Extjs 4.1.1.

Can we have Grid with readonly feature i.e. for specific columns, can we make it readonly

Even we have cell edito on for that column ?

Comment: yes, we can able to make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can able to achieve through event(before edit) . please refer below link for reference with example

- Extjs 3

http://techneerajnandwana.blogspot.in/2011/10/javascript-extjs3-editorgridpanel-read.html
[EXtjs 3.2 :How do I Set the specific cell as uneditable or read only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982728/extjs-3-2-how-do-i-set-the-specific-cell-as-uneditable-or-read-only)

- Extjs 4

[ExtJS 4 RowEditing disable edit on one column based on record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679364/extjs-4-rowediting-disable-edit-on-one-column-based-on-record)